# BASH script editor to/from single line commands

Tags: shell-script, editors

Is there an editor (or plugin/extension) that supports folding and unfolding `bash` scripts to/from single line commands? Suppose I am writing two nested for loops and I'd like to visually edit the script with indentation but then I'd like to easily paste it to a terminal in a single line format.

Comment: Multi-line loops or conditional statements may be pasted directly into the terminal without causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with kate editor. In config search for

```
beginRegion starts a code folding block. Default: unset.
endRegion closes a code folding block. Default: unset.
```

and set them accordingly

Check [this](https://kate-editor.org/2005/03/24/writing-a-syntax-highlighting-file/) page for more information